# How to pass props to Tab Routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

What is the best way to pass props to tab screens?

```js
return(
  <NavigateionContainer>
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <TabScreen name="FeedStack" component={FeedStack}  />
      <TabScreen name="Practice" component={Practice}  />
      <TabScreen name="Notifications" component={Notifications}  />
      <TabScreen name="Chat" component={Chat}  />
      <TabScreen name="Settings" component={Settings}  />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  </NavigateionContainer>
);
```

Comment: Image fails to load for me. Please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example of your code, and detailed information about what you are trying to do, what issue you have, what you're tried, and what your expected result *should* be.

Answer (score 0):

Just because its a tab screen, doesn't mean passing parameters to it is different to other navigator screens. To pass params as screen props (from [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/)):

```
<Stack.Screen
  name="Details"
  component={DetailsScreen}
  initialParams={{ itemId: 42 }}
/>
```